# how to show what video files are on iPad

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad and need to delete some files. Unfortunately, I can't tell where the videos are based upon this:

[image]

Everything appears to be purchased on iCloud. Is there a way I can click to see what actual files are on my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the On my iPad tab at the top of iTunes. Here, the contents of your iPad is listed. Choose Movies to show all the movies on your iPad which are accounting for the space shown in your image.